# How to pass extra parameter in Spring login

Tags: java, spring

I am using Spring framework. At the login page you have to enter Username and password.

Now the user should also enter his role when logging in. So I put a combo box there where you can select role: Admin, User or Manager. So I extended the available function to be able to also process post. But somehow the combobox value is never received by this method. It seems spring filters it before.

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/", "/login" }, method = {RequestMethod.GET,RequestMethod.POST})
public String loginPage(@RequestParam(required=false) String role) {
    if (isCurrentAuthenticationAnonymous()) {
        return "login";
    } else {
        return "redirect:/user/workingtimeNow" ;
    }
}
```

As you can see I added RequestMethod.POST and @RequestParam(required=false) String role  . But role is always null.

Comment: Does it really make sense for a user that is logging in to be able to select their role? Hi, I was previous a User but now i'm an Admin, yipee.

Comment: You should store the role for a specific user wherever you store the user info. Then, when a user logs in, you can pass the user's role to the Spring security using the UserDetailsSecurityImpl class

Comment: Ok. I found a class SecurityConfig which extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter   . Does the name of the class matter. Does Spring look exactly for this class name . Or could I also name it MySecurityConfig ??